# dont find the view in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Hi everyone I am using joomla 2.5 for a website

I create a component to insert products in the data base in the back-end, and I want to show this product in front-end

I have this link in the view to show a products with type=1;

```
 <div class="col2"><a href="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/index.php/hardware/integrados">Productos</a></div>
```

In the front-end of the component controller.php I have this

```
class HardwareController extends JController
    function integrados(){
            $model = &$this->getModel(JRequest::getCmd('view'));
            $view  = &$this->getView(JRequest::getCmd('view'), 'html');
        $view->setModel($model, true);
        $view->hardwareIntegrado();
    }
```

in my model I have

```
class HardwareModelHardwares extends JModelList 
     function getIntegrados(){
         $db=& JFactory::getDBO();
         $query= "SELECT *
            FROM ".$db->nameQuote('#__hardware')."
            WHERE ".$db->nameQuote('tipo')."=".$db->quote("1").";";
         $db->setQuery( $query);
         $restaurantes=$db->loadObjectList();
         JRequest::setVar('hard', $restaurantes);
         return $restaurantes;
    }
```

and in my view.html.php I have this

```
public function hardwareIntegrado(){
    $this->assignRef('pagination', $this->get('pagination'));
    $this->assignRef('hardware', $this->get('integrados'));
    $this->assignRef('list', $this->get('list'));
    parent::display();
}
```

When I click to the link I obtain this error

```
500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: hardware, html, hardwareView
```

any idea!

Comment: What is class name and path of your view?

Comment: Hi @WooDzu the path of my view is in the component of frontend views/hardwares/tmpl/default.php.  I have been doing change JJRequest::getCmd is deprecate. If I have this in  the end of the controller this work $view  = JFactory::getApplication()->input->getCmd('view', 'hardwares');
JFactory::getApplication()->input->set('view', $view); any idea!

Comment: The path you wrote is a template path not view.
What is the path to view.html.php? and what class it contains?

Comment: @WooDzu the path of view.html.php is com_hardware/views/hardwares/view.html.php and the class is       class HardwareViewHardwares extends JView

Answer (score 1):

You should change your view class to **hardwareViewHardware**

Comment: thanks @WooDzu but dont work too                                     500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: hardware, html, hardwareView

Comment: It has to extend JView. Copy from another view.

Comment: Is this the only view you have in this component? If there are any other do they work? If that's the only one, you should be looking at your main controllers code

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error-

```
500 - View not found [name, type, prefix]: hardware, html, hardwareView
```

because it's looking for `hardware` view.In the link- `index.php/hardware/integrados` it seems  you are passing `view=hardware` . Whereas everywhere you have defined it as `hardwares` like in folder name and class.Either change link or class and folder.

Hope this will help.